# A home networking disaster

Tags: networking, network-printer

I am trying to set up home networking, between a PC with Windows (has only wired LAN), a laptop with Linux (has Wifi and Wired LAN) and a printer (I want to use the printer only using wired LAN), but I'm running into a few surprisingly annoying problems: My home router that has been given by the ISP to me (FibreHome AN5506) has two ports. When I connect my PC to any of them, I can access the internet without problems. Also, I'm usually connecting my laptop via Wifi, and sometimes there are other Wifi devices lying around such as tablets or an internet radio.

**Weird problem 1:** When I try to connect my network printer, a Brother T910DW, sometimes the printer will tell me through a small display if his it has an IP address that is totally outside the DHCP IP address range than I set on the router (the address then starts with 169.256... which seems to be related to the APIPA protocol, but I have also seen the address 192.0.0.192 one time); only once it actually got an IP address that was within that range.
But in any of these cases the printer is not seen from my PC; even though its MAC address does sometimes appear -though with a different IP address that the router displays, namely an IP address that is within the DHCP range- when I list all DHCP clients.

**Weird problem 2:** If I put a simple switch before one of the ports and connect my PC to the switch, then my PC isn't able to reach the  internet anymore, nor can I access the IP address of the router.

**Weird problem 3:** When I connect the printer to my laptop via a LAN cable, I can see the printer, but I cannot add it somehow ("unable to add printer").
When I connect via WIFI to the router, I can see the printer oddly and I can add it, and I print - even if the router displays the 169.254 ... address but it **does not appear on the DHCP client list**. How is it even possible to print in this case?

**Can someone figure out what is going on here?** Somehow, all of this seems to be a huge mess! I don't even know how to get started on this, I have tried resetting everything in turn (I even did a major Windows network reset), changing cables etc., nothing is working.  I'd appreciate any halp.

Comment: You have 3 or more devices and so the ISP Router with 2 ports is not enough if all is to be wired (as you said).   Get a small 4 or 8 port Router, hook it it up to Port 1 of the ISP device. Set up your router to service all your devices.  Give the Printer a Static IP address on your network or it will tend to get lost.

Comment: Its possible another device on the network gets the same IP address as the printer, and a duplicate IP address is not allowed, so the printer can't get one. Make sure the printer does not have a static ip address, or if that's the only way, ensure that its set to anything outside of the DHCP scope, but in range of the network.

Comment: @John I have a feeling the printer already has a static ip, but is set to one that the DHCP server also gives out and a duplicate ip collision happens, making the printer jump to a different ip address.

Comment: @John Ah, maybe I wasn't clear (I edited my question now to make sure I'm clear): Only the printer I want to be wired. The PC has to be wired, but I am totally fine using the laptop only via Wifi (and there are some other Wifi devices occasionally on too, such as a tablet or an internet radio). I would really not change my router, because my ISP gave it to me and my phone is connected to it too, so I would probably have to spend a significant amount of time researching and finding another model that works interchangeably.

Comment: @LPChip I also thought of that, but that isn't the case, no duplicate IP, I checked all the DHCP clients that appear (not that many) and figured out by the MAC address what each if them were. Most of my experimenting I did with the printer set to DHCP. The problem seems to be something more ... sinister as I can print, as explained (#3) but only via Wifi.

Comment: does your simple switch have a designated "uplink port"? Many modern lan devices are auto-sensing/switching but not guaranteed. Not using a crossover cable is probably the explanation for your direct connection pc-to-printer not working. direct connections without a crossover cable means transmit is connected to transmit on both ends

Comment: @Yorik No, it has no designated uplink port (I was actually wondering about that). Good point about the crossover cable; is there any way (easier than inspecting the colored wires at the end) that I can check which of the cables I have is crossover or not?